# HIbernate gives unknown entity exception

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

This is my model classes(AppInfo , Userinfo)

```
@Entity
@Table(appliesTo="appinfo")
public class AppInfo  {

    @Id
    @Column(name="appid")
    private int appId;

    @Column(name="appname")
    private String appName;

    @Column(name="roleid")
    private int roleId;

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY,targetEntity=UserInfo.class,cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="Appid",referencedColumnName="appid")
    private Set<UserInfo> userInfo;

        // setters & getters
}

@Entity
@Table(appliesTo = "userinfo")
public class UserInfo {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "userid")
    private int userId;

    @Column(name = "username")
    private String userName;

            @Column(name = "hoid")
            private String hoId;
//setters & getters
    }
```

My hbm config file

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">false</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/taskdb</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping class="com.myproject.hibernate.model.UserInfo.java"></mapping>
        <mapping class="com.myproject.hibernate.model.AppInfo.java"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
```

My utility class

```
   public class UtilityAnnotation {


                private static final SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

                @SuppressWarning

s("deprecation")
            private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
                try {
                    // Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
                    return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                } catch (Throwable ex) {
                    // Make sure you log the exception, as it might be swallowed
                    System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
                    throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
                }
            }

            public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
                return sessionFactory;
            }

            public static void shutdown() {
                // Close caches and connection pools
                getSessionFactory().close();
            }

    }
```

And finally main class

```
public class OneToMany {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Session session = UtilityAnnotation.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        UserInfo info = new UserInfo();
        AppInfo ap = new AppInfo();

        ap.setAppId(1);
        ap.setAppName("Check");
        ap.setRoleId(1);

        info.setUserName("Grey");
        info.setUserId(4);
        info.setHoneyId("4");

        Set<UserInfo> mys = new HashSet<UserInfo>();
        mys.add(info);

        ap.setUserInfo(mys);

        session.save(ap);
        session.getTransaction().commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

when I run the main class Iget following error

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity: com.myproject.hibernate.model.AppInfo
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionFactoryImpl.java:693)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.getEntityPersister(SessionImpl.java:1485)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:120)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:210)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedOrRequestedId(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:195)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveEventListener.performSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveEventListener.java:50)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.onSaveOrUpdate(DefaultSaveOrUpdateEventListener.java:93)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.fireSave(SessionImpl.java:713)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:701)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.save(SessionImpl.java:697)
    at com.myproject.hibernate.practice.OneToMany.main(OneToMany.java:32)
```

I searched for solution and in many have told to change the config file mapping where class path should be correct but I have given the right class path so whats the mistake I am making here.

I also have a separate main class which adds info into userinfo and that works perfectly.

Comment: Consider posting an SSCCE - http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add your entities using annotation, you need to add your annotated entities in the configuration object

```
new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(AppInfo.class).addAnnotatedClass(UserInfo.class).buildSessionFactory();
```

also remove **.java** from the mapping class xml configuration if you are using xml configuration

Comment: Hi I made change to my utilityannotaion class
return new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(AppInfo.class).addAnnotatedClass(UserInfo.class).buildSessionFactory();

and removed the .java but same error exist

Comment: I have another main class which includeds data into userinfo , that works fine only when i try one to many it does not

Comment: for one-to-many issue please create a new question and post your mapping entities code

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
    <mapping class="com.myproject.hibernate.model.UserInfo.java"></mapping>
    <mapping class="com.myproject.hibernate.model.AppInfo.java"></mapping>
```

with

```
    <mapping class="com.myproject.hibernate.model.UserInfo"/>
    <mapping class="com.myproject.hibernate.model.AppInfo"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Java to include Entity instead of xml, it's more maintainable and readable for fellow developers.

Current exception is due to  .java in the mapping class xml configuration

If you want to add your entities using annotation, prefer to add your annotated entities in the configuration object

```
    new AnnotationConfiguration().configure().addAnnotatedClass(AppInfo.class).addAnnotatedClass(UserInfo.class).buildSessionFactory();
```